# How can I restructure data to count/plot every time a unique string value has TRUE values in other columns in r?

Tags: r

I have a data set with string variables and columns with TRUE/FALSE values. Here is an extremely simplified dummy data set:

```
IDs       <- c("a",   "a",   "b",   "c",   "d",   "d",  "d",   "e",   "f",  "g")
variable1 <- c(TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
variable2 <- c(FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
variable3 <- c(TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE)
df        <- data.frame(IDs, variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

I want to generate a bar plot with the variables 1, 2 and 3 as the x-axis and the y-axis as the counts for unique string values when variable 1,2 and 3 are TRUE. I think I need to reshape the data in some way before passing it to ggplot, although I'm not sure how.

Essentially I want it to look like this:

```
IDs_r       <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
variable1_r <- c(1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0)
variable2_r <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
variable3_r <- c(2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0)
df_r        <- data.frame(IDs_r, variable1_r, variable2_r, variable3_r)
```

After I reshape my data, how can I generate a bar plot looking at the counts of unique strings between my three variables?

EDIT:
After getting the group sum output my next question is regarding the plot. The way I want the plot to look is to have each variable have its own bar, 3 separate bars for variable 1,2, and 3. I want a count of unique strings in the bar plot - so if "a" is TRUE for variable 1 at least one time it will only count once in other words if "a" is TRUE twice it will still only count one time.

EDIT EDIT:
I'm just settling for using multiple ifelse() functions like this:

````
```{r}
library(dplyr)
IDs <- c("a","a","b","c","d","d","d","e","f","g")
variable1 <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
variable2 <- c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)
variable3 <- c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)

df <- data.frame(IDs,variable1,variable2,variable3)

df_new<-df %>% group_by(IDs) %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)

df_new$variable1<-ifelse(df_new$variable1 >= 1, 1, 0)
df_new$variable2<-ifelse(df_new$variable2 >= 1, 1, 0)
df_new$variable3<-ifelse(df_new$variable3 >= 1, 1, 0)

df_new %>%
group_by(IDs) %>% 
 summarise(across(everything(), sum)) 
 %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -IDs) %>%
 ggplot() + 
 aes(name, value, fill = IDs) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity")

df_new
```
````

Comment: Your data transformation is a grouped sum. With `dplyr`, `df_r = df %>% group_by(IDs) %>% summarize_all(sum)`. Can you be more specific about your plot? I can't tell if `IDs` is supposed to be discernible in the plot through color or something, or if it is aggregated up. "Count of unique strings" would suggest max of 1 per ID, but your `df_r` has 2s and 3s in it...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me, you're right that is unclear, I will make an edit in my original post. I did mean count of unique strings. I want to have 3 bars of variables. so variable 1, 2, and 3 will each have their own bars. I want a count of unique strings in the bar plot - so if "a" is TRUE for variable 1 at least one time it will only count once in other words if "a" is TRUE twice it will still only count one time.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're asking how to aggregate data, or plot. Regarding the former, in `dplyr` you could do

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(IDs) %>% summarise_all(sum)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  IDs   variable1 variable2 variable3
#  <fct>     <int>     <int>     <int>
#1 a             1         1         2
#2 b             1         0         0
#3 c             0         1         0
#4 d             2         1         3
#5 e             0         0         1
#6 f             1         1         1
#7 g             0         1         0
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
 group_by(IDs) %>%
 summarise(across(everything(), max)) %>%
 tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -IDs) %>%
 ggplot() + 
 aes(name, value, fill = IDs) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Or do you want one with `position = "dodge"` ?

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this is close to what I am looking for, but I've edited my original post now to clarify, now that I see how convoluted it was. What I want is a plot that counts once if "a" has TRUE at least once, and if "a" has TRUE twice it still only counts it once.

Comment: @JacobWhite In that case, I think you should use `max`. See my updated answer.